# Android Emulator does not install my application

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Here's my issue:
I created an application with eclipse and I've already tested it on my Galaxy Ace. Everything works fine.
I need to make it work on the emulator too, so I created a new AVD and I started my application. As soon as the emulator appears I unlock it and there is no trace of my application. I've searched in every menu.
So, I tried with a simple "Hello World" project but it's the same.
I've also tried to stop the adb.exe process and I tried with the "kill-server" / "start-server" combination with no success.

The weird thing is that there are no errors displayed in LogCat window, and the DDMS perspective does not recognize any virtual device.

Also, I tried typing "adb -e devices" in console (of course, after I started a new emulator), but it seems it could not find any device.

Someone knows how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

Here the steps:

1.Start the virtual device

2.Open the DDMS perspective

3.Open console, in the "platform-tools" directory type "adb kill-server"

4.Now, type "adb devices"

5.Check your DDMS perspective, now you should see the virtual device

Answer (score 1):

change your workspace, create a new one... that helped me.. or if still not, reinstall the eclipse and plugins..

also, i'd encounter that my doesnt install because i changed the android:name in manifest of the launcher activity.. dont change it keep it

```
  <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: Tried to change workspace.. still the same. I did not touch the android name. I will try to re-install, then I'll let you know. Thanks for yor help!